# Add properties to large GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, json

I have a geojson of multipolygons like so

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ADMIN": "Aruba",
        "ISO_A3": "ABW"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -69.99693762899992,
              12.577582098000036
            ],
            [
              -69.93639075399994,
              12.53172435100005
...
```

Using Python, I would like to simply add more properties to every feature in the feature collection. I would like to add these properties from a Python dictionary.

So I would take dictionary values and write them to the properties in each feature.

I've been a little lost so far frankly.

Comment: Wecome to GIS SE. As a newish user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here need to not only frame the goal, but show work toward accomplishing that goal, and explain the exact problem encountered in that attempt. Processing JSON text to a dictionary with Python is a single function (`json.loads()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short code that adds properties to a GeoJSON from a Python dictionary:

```
import json

with open('yourgeojson.geojson', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#A Python dictionary containing properties to be added to each GeoJSON Feature
properties_dict={
    "property1": "foo",
    "property2": 10,
    "property3": 100
    }
#Convert the dictionary to a list
properties_list=zip(properties_dict.keys(),properties_dict.values())

#Loop over GeoJSON features and add the new properties
for feat in data['features']:
    for i in range(len(properties_list)):
        feat ['properties'][properties_list[i][0]]=properties_list[i][1]

#Write result to a new file
with open('new.geojson', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and I appreciate the help! Would you have any guidance as to how to do this if the properties for each feature need to be different? To put it in better context I am trying to append World Bank literacy data to each country in a GeoJson of all world countries. So I have many years with values for each year for each individual country.

Comment: That's a separate question than your original question. If I solved your current question please accept the answer (green arrow). In general, you can achieve that by means of having a mutual field in the dictionary and the geojson, and then joining them together by looping on both. If that fails, feel free to ask a new question or edit this one, demonstrating your attempts.

Comment: @claytongroth instead of the `zip` line, in the feat loop just do: `feat ['properties'].update(properties_dict)`. That will incorporate everything in your external dict into the feature's properties.